# PHP fetch object key

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I have a javascript object I have created for a multidimensional array, see below:

```
var myObject = {};

myObject['firstArray'] = ['firstValue', 'secondValue'];
myObject['secondArray'] = ['firstValue', 'secondValue'];
```

I then use the JSON stringify function to prepare it to pass to a PHP page:

```
arrayToPass = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

In the PHP page I then decode the object:

```
$passedObject = file_get_contents( "php://input" );

$splitObject = json_decode($passedObject);
```

I then loop through the splitObject to extract the values:

```
foreach($splitObject as $array){
      echo ($array);
      echo"<br>";
     foreach($array as $value){
        echo $value;
            echo "<br>";
     }
  }
```

The ouput is below:

```
Array
firstValue
secondValue

Array
firstValue
secondValue
```

Is there a way I can get the output to display the actual array name rather than just Array, so the results should be:

```
firstArray
firstValue
secondValue

secondArray
firstValue
secondValue
```

I tried to use `echo key($array)` but that just returns 0, due to it being an object rather than an array I believe.

Comment: Decode the JSON as an array (`json_decode($passedObject, TRUE)`), then use `foreach($splitObject as $key=>$array){ echo($key); //... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try with:

```
foreach ($splitObject as $key => $array) {
    echo $key;
    echo '<br/>';

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo $value;
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}
```